# I made a text game and suddenly it has stopped working

Tags: java

I updated it today and suddenly it has stopped working. As soon as I put in any text it will go to the next line and just freeze. I tried removing the part that I added and now it still does that. I am gonna post the code below but it's really massive [400+ lines] so it will take a bit to read if any of you can figure out whats wrong. Thank you in advance!

```
    import java.util.*;

public class OpeningGame
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String spooky;
        int commonkey = 5;
        int money = 0;
        int uncommon = 0;
        int common = 0;
        int rare = 0;
        int legendary = 0;
        int exotic = 0;
        int number = 0;
        int keyinput;
        int relic = 0;
        int rarekey = 0;
        String sellterm;
        int sell;
        int legendarykey = 0;
        int rune = 0;
        int xp = 0;
        int level = 1;
        int xpcap = 100;
        int doublesell = 1;
        int upgradepoint = 0;
        String upgradeterm;
        int earnupgrade = 1;
        int exotickey = 0;
        int ancient = 0;
        int prestige = 0;


        System.out.println("Type case to see your cases. Type open common to open a common case. Type open rare to open a rare case. Type buy common to buy a common key.");
        System.out.println("Type money to check money. Type sell to sell your items. Type inventory to see your items. Type ");
        System.out.println("Type buy rare to buy a rare key. Type buy legendary to buy a legendary key. Type open legendary to open a legendary case");
        do
        {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.print("Enter a keyword: ");
            spooky = keyboard.nextLine();


            if (spooky.equals("xp"))
            {
                System.out.println(xp + "/" + xpcap);
            }


//          COMMON CASE OPENINGS

            if (spooky.equals("open common") || spooky.equals("Open Common"))
            {
                if (commonkey >= 1)
                {
                    number = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
                        if (number < 51 && number >= 1)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found a common.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            common ++;
                            xp += 10;
                        }
                        else if (number < 55 && number >= 51)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found a legendary!");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            legendary ++;
                            xp += 75;
                        }
                        else if (number < 59 && number >= 55)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found an EXOTIC!");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            exotic++;
                            xp += 250;
                        }
                        else if (number < 66 && number >= 59)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found a rare!");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            rare++;
                            xp += 50;
                        }
                        else if (number <= 100 && number >= 66)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found an uncommon");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            uncommon++;
                            xp += 25;
                        }
                commonkey--;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("You do not have any keys. Buy some");
                }
            }

//           RARE CASE OPENINGS
            if (spooky.equals("open rare") || spooky.equals("Open Rare"))
            {
                if (rarekey >= 1)
                {
                    number = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
                        if (number < 51 && number >= 1)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found a common.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            common ++;
                            xp += 10;
                        }
                        else if (number < 80 && number >= 51)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found a legendary!");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            legendary ++;
                            xp += 75;
                        }
                        else if (number < 95 && number >= 80)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found an EXOTIC!");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            exotic++;
                            xp += 250;
                        }
                        else if (number <= 100 && number >= 95)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found a RELIC!!!!");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            relic++;
                            xp += 1000;
                        }
                rarekey--;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("You do not have any keys. Buy some");
                }
            }

//         Legendary case

            if (spooky.equals("open legendary") || spooky.equals("Open Legendary"))
            {
                if (legendarykey >= 1)
                {
                    number = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
                        if (number < 25 && number >= 1)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found a rare.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            rare ++;
                            xp += 50;
                        }
                        else if (number < 51 && number >= 25)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found a legendary!");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            legendary ++;
                            xp += 75;
                        }
                        else if (number < 70 && number >= 51)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found an EXOTIC!");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            exotic++;
                            xp += 250;
                        }
                        else if (number <= 95 && number >= 70)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found a RELIC!!!!");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            relic++;
                            xp += 1000;
                        }
                        else if (number <= 100 && number >= 95)
                        {
                            System.out.println("YOU FOUND A RUNE!!!!");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            rune++;
                            xp += 10000;
                        }
                legendarykey--;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("You do not have any keys. Buy some");
                }
            }



            if (spooky.equals("open exotic") || spooky.equals("Open Exotic"))
            {
                if (exotickey >= 1)
                {
                    number = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
                        if (number < 25 && number >= 1)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found a rare.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            rare ++;
                            xp += 50;
                        }
                        else if (number < 51 && number >= 25)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found a exotic!");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            exotic ++;
                            xp += 250;
                        }
                        else if (number < 70 && number >= 51)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found a RELIC!");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            relic++;
                            xp += 1000;
                        }
                        else if (number <= 95 && number >= 70)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You found a RUNE!!!!");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            rune++;
                            xp += 10000;
                        }
                        else if (number <= 100 && number >= 95)
                        {
                            System.out.println("YOU FOUND AN ANCIENT!!!!");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            ancient++;
                            xp += 100000;
                        }
                exotickey--;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("You do not have any keys. Buy some");
                }
            }

            if (spooky.equals("buy common") || spooky.equals("Buy Common"))
            {
                System.out.println("Type how many keys you would like to buy: ");
                keyinput = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (money >= (5 * keyinput))
                {
                    commonkey = commonkey + keyinput;
                    money = money - (keyinput * 5);
                }
                else if (money < (5 * keyinput))
                {
                    System.out.println("You do not have enough money for the keys.");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
            }

            if (spooky.equals("levelcheck"))
            {
                System.out.println("You are level " + level + ". You are prestige " + prestige + ".");
            }


            if (spooky.equals("buy rare") || spooky.equals("Buy Rare"))
            {
                System.out.println("Type how many keys you would like to buy: ");
                keyinput = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (money >= (250 * keyinput))
                {
                    rarekey = rarekey + keyinput;
                    money = money - (keyinput * 250);
                }
                else if (money < (250 * keyinput))
                {
                    System.out.println("You do not have enough money for the keys.");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
            }

//                   legendary key

            if (spooky.equals("buy legendary") || spooky.equals("Buy Legendary"))
            {
                System.out.println("Type how many keys you would like to buy: ");
                keyinput = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (money >= (2500 * keyinput))
                {
                    legendarykey = legendarykey + keyinput;
                    money = money - (keyinput * 2500);
                }
                else if (money < (2500 * keyinput))
                {
                    System.out.println("You do not have enough money for the keys.");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
            }

            if (spooky.equals("buy exotic") || spooky.equals("Buy Exotic"))
            {
                System.out.println("Type how many keys you would like to buy: ");
                keyinput = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (money >= (250000 * keyinput))
                {
                    exotickey = exotickey + keyinput;
                    money = money - (keyinput * 250000);
                }
                else if (money < (250000 * keyinput))
                {
                    System.out.println("You do not have enough money for the keys.");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
            }



            if (spooky.equals("money") || spooky.equals("Money"))
            {
                System.out.println("You have $" + money + ".");
                System.out.println(" ");
            }



            if (spooky.equals("inventory") || spooky.equals("Inventory"))
            {
                System.out.println("You have " + common + " commons. You have " + uncommon + " uncommons. You have " + rare + " rares. You have " + legendary + " legendaries. You have " + exotic + " exotics. You have " + relic + " relics. You have " + rune + " runes.");
                System.out.println("You have " + ancient + " ancients.");
                System.out.println(" ");
            }


            if (spooky.equals("earn") || spooky.equals("Earn"))
            {
                System.out.println("+ $1");
                money += (1 * earnupgrade);
            }


            if (spooky.equals("prestige") || spooky.equals("Prestige"))
            {
                if (level >= 12)
                {
                    level = 1;
                    money = 500;
                    prestige++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("You are not level 12. You cannot prestige.");
                }
            }

            do
            {
                if (xp >= xpcap)
                {
                    level++;
                    upgradepoint++;
                    xp = 0;
                    xpcap = xpcap * 2;
                    System.out.println("You are now level " + level + "!");
                }
            }
            while (level < 12);

//          UPGRADE SHOP

            if (spooky.equals("upgrade") || spooky.equals("Upgrade"))
            {
                System.out.println("Type the name of what upgrade you would like. Use correct capititalization");
                System.out.println("Selling Price : Double the selling price on all items. 3 upgrade points.");
                System.out.println("Earn Double : Double the money you earn by typing earn. 1 upgrade point.");
                upgradeterm = keyboard.nextLine();
                if (upgradeterm.equals("Selling Price"))
                {
                    if (upgradepoint >= 3)
                    {
                        upgradepoint -= 3;
                        doublesell = doublesell * 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("You do not have enough upgrade points");
                    }
                }
                if (upgradeterm.equals("Earn Double"))
                {
                    if (upgradepoint >= 1)
                    {
                        upgradepoint -= 1;
                        earnupgrade = earnupgrade * 2;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("You do not have enough upgrade points");
                    }
                }
            }


//              SHOP
            if (spooky.equals("sell") || spooky.equals("Sell"))
            {
                System.out.println("What items would you like to sell: ");
                sellterm = keyboard.nextLine();

                if (sellterm.equals("common") || sellterm.equals("Common"))
                {
                    money = money + ((3 * common) * doublesell);
                    System.out.println("+ $" + ((3 * common) * doublesell));
                    common = 0;
                }
                else if (sellterm.equals("uncommon") || sellterm.equals("Uncommon"))
                {
                    money = money + ((7 * uncommon) * doublesell);
                    System.out.println("+ $" + ((7 * uncommon) * doublesell));
                    uncommon = 0;
                }
                else if (sellterm.equals("rare") || sellterm.equals("Rare"))
                {
                    money = money + ((25 * rare) * doublesell);
                    System.out.println("+ $" + ((25 * rare) * doublesell));
                    rare = 0;
                }
                else if (sellterm.equals("legendary") || sellterm.equals("Legendary"))
                {
                    money = money + ((100 * legendary) * doublesell);
                    System.out.println("+ $" + ((100 * legendary) * doublesell));
                    legendary = 0;
                }
                else if (sellterm.equals("exotic") || sellterm.equals("Exotic"))
                {
                    money = money + ((500 * exotic) * doublesell);
                    System.out.println("+ $" + ((500 * exotic) * doublesell));
                    exotic = 0;
                }
                else if (sellterm.equals("relic") || sellterm.equals("Relic"))
                {
                    money = money + ((5000 * relic) * doublesell);
                    System.out.println("+ $" + ((5000 * relic) * doublesell));
                    relic = 0;
                }
                else if (sellterm.equals("rune") || sellterm.equals("Rune"))
                {
                    money = money + ((50000 * rune) * doublesell);
                    System.out.println("+ $" + ((50000 * rune) * doublesell));
                    rune = 0;
                }
                else if (sellterm.equals("ancient") || sellterm.equals("Ancient"))
                {
                    money = money + ((100000 * ancient) * doublesell);
                    System.out.println("+ $" + ((100000 * ancient) * doublesell));
                    ancient = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        while (!spooky.equals("quit"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you change? Assuming you had this in git or Mercurial or some other version-control system, start by `diff`ing the changes and thinking about what effects they might have.

Comment: It is perfect time to learn how to use debugger of your favourite IDE.

Comment: Anyway I suspect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods

Comment: You should read about refactoring... Put some statements out in own methods and name them about what they're doing. Then your code becomes much more understandable. See also "Object Calisthenics" (e.g. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2081135/core-java/object-calisthenics-change-the-way-you-code.html)